# FTSearch escaping Wildcards programmatically

Tags: lotus-domino

I am trying to translate user input into something that the FTSearch will understand and making the search as 'google-like' as possible (since that's what the users are expecting)

So I translate

```
Superman Batman
```

into

```
(*Superman* OR *Batman*)
```

I've been battering my search with test units and I thought about a user actually searching for * or ? in the string. How does one escape these? They work in the client, i.e. if I input

```
*
```

I get

```
Contrived*Bizarrename
```

but I haven't been able to do this programatically.

I'm using

```
foundNotesDocuments = db.FTSearch(getCoolFTString(this.searchText), this.maxResults);
```

Is this at all possible?

Comment: from where do you FTsearch ?

Comment: from where do you FTsearch ?
http://www.acme.com/db.nsf/myView/? SearchView&Query=[Myfield]="\*Superman\*"&SearchFuzzy=TRUE&SearchWV=true
or notesDatabase.FTSearch( query$, maxdocs%, [ sortoptions% ], [ otheroptions% ] )
try using DOUBLE STAR: "**" I used this but I don't remember if it searched actually 2 stars or also 1

Comment: Does it work if you surround your * by "*"?